# Accuracy of Distance between two lat long ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps

I am calculating the distance between two lat long coordinates using `-(CLLocation)distanceFomLocation:(CLLocation)` and Haversine formula. But its not giving the correct result. 
I am using core location framework to find out the lat long of two posions which are 1 meter apart in actual but the above formula gives the distance  some times 40m sometimes 30m and so on. I have set the desired accuracy is ten meters. I am using iPhone 4s device.

Just want to know that what is accuracy of method `-(CLLocation)distanceFomLocation:(CLLocation)` for calculating the distances?  I have to calculate the distances whth in 10 m range.

Comment: What are the actual lat and log coordinates?

Comment: I have got so many pairs using iPhone 4s. Here is one of them.28.534790 77.345671  and 28.534172 77.345350. Actually I am getting these just 1 or 2 meter radius from my desk.

Comment: These points are 39 meters apart.. See Alex's Answer

Comment: Read my answer, If you are sitting on you desk, you probably are inside a building, then forget GPS. you get a coordinate because you are sitting near the window. But this is one of the worst situations. Go outside, and check that you have good view to sky. go away from buildings with reflective surfaces (glass or metall)

Comment: upvoted, you now can upvote, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is correct, for 1m distance the acuarcy is under 1/1000 of milimeter. That what is wrong is your lat/lon position you got from the GPS device, which can deviate that 40m.

For 10m distance the formula used in either haversine or `distanceFromLocation` are perfectly accurate. It starts to get interesting when distances are some kilometer apart.

So don't worry. But yor main problem is to get such acurate positions, and that depends what you need it for.

Do you need distance meassure of the coordinates of ONE GPS device, (that works) or between differnet GPS devices (can be appart 30m for two device on same position, but usually 3-6m GPS accuracy when having good view to open sky.

Further make sure that you use desiredAccuracy BestForNavigation or Best.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tested indoors in building but its not given me correct result. Our major concern is to make it work everywhere correctlly.

Comment: forget it, that does not work, nobody in the world can do that!

Comment: GPS does not work accurately indoors. Even outdoors the accuracy can easily be +-several meters. That's just how it is.

Comment: consider Wifi for locating in a (known) building with many wifi access points

Comment: We need to measure the distance between different GPS devices within 10 m range.

Comment: that works only outside, and only in normal situations. insituaion with bad view tom sky its about 30m

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for quick reply. Any other way to find out the distance between two devices whithin 10 m range that works every where?

Comment: stop dreaming. inside you own building, you can consider wifi, but probably not with ios. you would need a device where you have full controll: query all wifi access points, with field strength.